# How can I do comparison within rolling intervals to obtain the 2 lowest values in R?

Tags: r, date, dplyr, data.table, intervals

I would like to obtain the 2 lowest values which are at least 3 months apart within a one-year interval.

This is the pseudo-code that I am thinking of:

1. Join `df1` and `df2` by ID
2. Group by ID and filter DATE within 1 year from INITIAL_DATE.
3. Extract the lowest 2 RESULT
4. Ensure they are at least 3 months apart. Else, exclude the second lowest and extract the third lowest RESULT (this is the part where I don't know how to proceed)
5. **EDIT** Repeat for Year 3 and Year 4.

Sample input data looks like this:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
ID  INITIAL_DATE
1   02/04/2015
2   06/01/2015", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
ID  DATE    RESULT
1   18/08/2015  93
1   28/10/2015  85
1   16/12/2015  49
1   12/01/2016  58
1   06/03/2016  65
1   17/03/2016  86
1   07/04/2016  79
1   28/06/2016  90
1   09/10/2016  44
1   24/10/2016  51
1   08/11/2016  72
1   03/02/2017  46
1   05/04/2017  50
1   12/05/2017  92
1   26/08/2017  56
1   03/11/2017  56
1   01/01/2018  93
1   15/03/2018  59
1   23/04/2018  80
1   16/07/2018  53
1   28/11/2018  100
2   06/05/2015  34
2   20/12/2015  23
2   21/02/2016  25
2   12/05/2016  54
2   20/03/2017  45
2   05/05/2017  39
2   02/06/2017  47
2   23/11/2017  56
2   03/03/2018  65
2   19/06/2018  45", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Sample output:

```
final_df <- read.table(text = "
ID  YEAR    DATE    RESULT
1   YEAR2   16/12/2015  49
1   YEAR2   07/04/2016  79
1   YEAR3   09/10/2016  44
1   YEAR3   03/02/2017  46
1   YEAR4   03/11/2017  56
1   YEAR4   16/07/2018  53
2   YEAR2   20/12/2015  23
2   YEAR2   12/05/2016  54
2   YEAR3   NA          NA
2   YEAR4   23/11/2017  56
2   YEAR4   19/06/2018  45", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Appreciate any suggestions or help with this! I'm more familiar with tidyverse, but happy to learn data.table format too!

Thank you in advance!

[image: Visual illustration of the question]

*Added some code sample to generate the output that I want. The code works but would like to see if there are more efficient ways to do this as my data has more than 20 million rows.*

```
pacman::p_load(dplyr, lubridate, tidyr, stringr, magrittr)

df2 %<>% 
  left_join(df1) %>%
  mutate(DATE = dmy(DATE), 
         INITIAL_DATE = dmy(INITIAL_DATE),
         DATE2 = INITIAL_DATE %m+% years(1),
         YEAR2 = if_else(DATE %within% interval(DATE2 %m-% days(180), DATE2 %m+% days(180)), 1L, 0L),
         DATE3 = INITIAL_DATE %m+% years(2),
         YEAR3 = if_else(DATE %within% interval(DATE3 %m-% days(180), DATE3 %m+% days(180)), 1L, 0L),
         DATE4 = INITIAL_DATE %m+% years(3),
         YEAR4 = if_else(DATE %within% interval(DATE4 %m-% days(180), DATE4 %m+% days(180)), 1L, 0L)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Y"),
               values_to = "include") %>%
  filter(include == 1L) %>%
  select(-matches("^DATE.$"), -include)

df2

year_min <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(ID, name) %>%
  # obtain the lowest result for each year
  slice_min(RESULT) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols  = c(ID, INITIAL_DATE),
              names_from = "name",
              values_from = c("DATE", "RESULT"))

# Find the second lowest RESULT for YEAR 2 which is at least 30 days from DATE_Y2
year2 <- year_min %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% filter(name=="YEAR2")) %>%
  filter(abs(difftime(DATE_YEAR2, DATE, units = "days")) >= 90) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice_min(RESULT) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(ID, INITIAL_DATE, matches("^(DATE|RESULT)_"), DATE_YEAR2_2 = DATE, RESULT_YEAR2_2 = RESULT)

year2

# Find the second lowest RESULT for YEAR 3 which is at least 30 days from DATE_Y3
year3 <- year_min %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% filter(name=="YEAR3")) %>%
  filter(abs(difftime(DATE_YEAR3, DATE, units = "days")) >= 90) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice_min(RESULT) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(ID, INITIAL_DATE, matches("^(DATE|RESULT)_"), DATE_YEAR3_2 = DATE, RESULT_YEAR3_2 = RESULT)
  
year3


# Find the second lowest RESULT for YEAR 4 which is at least 30 days from DATE_Y4
year4 <- year_min %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% filter(name=="YEAR4")) %>%
  filter(abs(difftime(DATE_YEAR4, DATE, units = "days")) >= 90) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice_min(RESULT) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(ID, INITIAL_DATE, matches("^(DATE|RESULT)_"), DATE_YEAR4_2 = DATE, RESULT_YEAR4_2 = RESULT)

year4


final_df <- full_join(year_min, year2) %>%
  full_join(year3) %>%
  full_join(year4)

final_df


final_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID, INITIAL_DATE),
               names_pattern = "(DATE|RESULT)_(YEAR.*)",
               names_to = c(".value", "YEAR")) %>%
  mutate(YEAR = str_remove(YEAR, "_.")) %>%
  arrange(ID, YEAR, RESULT) %>%
  group_by(ID, YEAR)
```

Comment: your result has years in 2017 and 2018, but when you join the two frames on ID and filter to within 1 year of INITIAL_DATE, you won't have any rows in those years.. Can you clarify what the exact output would be given your provided example data? (or expand the example data so that it indeed produces the output that you show)?

Comment: @langtang Thanks for the question! I've modified the pseudo-code to make it clearer. I would need to repeat the steps again for Year 3 and Year 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses a helper function to look at all pairwise combinations of difference-in-days between a set of dates, filters those combinations with >=90 differences, and returns the indexes (rows) that have the lowest values

1. Helper function

```
f <- function(d,v) {
  if(length(d)<2) return(NA)
  rows = do.call(rbind,combn(
    1:length(d),2, function(x) data.frame(r1 = x[1], r2 = x[2], ddiff = d[x[2]] - d[x[1]], v1= v[x[1]], v2 = v[x[2]]),simplify=F)
  ) %>% 
    filter(ddiff>=90) %>% 
    arrange(v1,v2) %>% 
    slice_head(n=1) %>% 
    select(r1,r2) %>% 
    t()
  if(dim(rows)[2]==0) return(NA)
  rows[,1]  
}
```

2. Pipeline to join, create `YEAR`, and call `f()` on the `ID/YEAR` groups

```
library(tidyverse)
inner_join(df1,df2,by="ID") %>% 
  mutate(across(2:3, ~as.Date(.x, "%d/%m/%Y"))) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(YEAR = ceiling(as.numeric((DATE-INITIAL_DATE+365.25/2) / 365.25))) %>% 
  arrange(ID,YEAR, DATE) %>% 
  group_by(ID,YEAR) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %in% f(DATE,RESULT))
```

Output:

```
      ID INITIAL_DATE DATE       RESULT  YEAR
   <int> <date>       <date>      <int> <dbl>
 1     1 2015-04-02   2015-12-16     49     2
 2     1 2015-04-02   2016-04-07     79     2
 3     1 2015-04-02   2016-10-09     44     3
 4     1 2015-04-02   2017-02-03     46     3
 5     1 2015-04-02   2017-11-03     56     4
 6     1 2015-04-02   2018-07-16     53     4
 7     2 2015-01-06   2015-12-20     23     2
 8     2 2015-01-06   2016-05-12     54     2
 9     2 2015-01-06   2017-11-23     56     4
10     2 2015-01-06   2018-06-19     45     4
```